# Disc brake conversion for Trek 7.5 FX from 2012

Tags: disc-brake, fork, conversion, rotor

Looking for a few tips to help me with a project. I got a [Trek 7.5 FX 2012](https://archive.trekbikes.com/us/en/2012/Trek/7_5_fx#/us/en/2012/Trek/7_5_fx/details) as a hand-me-down and love the bike, but I am having trouble getting used to the brakes. I would like to do a conversion to disc brakes but I have never done a project like this before. I am an apartment dweller and so this is the only bike I have for commuting so I also can not afford to have it out of commission for an extended period of time while I tinker with it. I am thinking I need a new fork, new front and back wheels, rotors, mechanical calipers, and a mounting system for the rear caliper on the frame. What parts specifically should I get and what advice should I listen to to avoid common pitfalls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an existing cyclocross bike to disc brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/683/converting-an-existing-cyclocross-bike-to-disc-brakes) (lots of others already asked and answered on this site)

Answer (score 1):

New fork, wheels and brakes is a significant art of the bike. You'd be better off selling the bike a buying a new one with disc brakes. Especially as the market for cheap MTBs or hybrids is exploding in the Washington DC region during the Corona pandemic. (Yes, I looked where you located, and that's where I live too)

Going the new bike route avoids screwing around with a rear disc brake converter and ensures you have a bike available at all times.

Alternatively, V-brakes really should be perfectly adequate and have sufficient stopping power and modulation for a road oriented hybrid. Have you considered having the brakes tuned, or perhaps upgrading the pads? Properly adjusted brakes and high end pads can make a great difference to braking performance.